# Remove NSArrayControllers selectedObjects on creation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a NSArrayController which gets populated using Cocoa Bindings from a CoreData NSMangedObject Model. When I check the contents of the controllers array the first model object is always present in selectedObjects.

This is a problem because I bind this ArrayController to a CollectionView and allow its items to be selectable by checking the 'Selectable' checkbox in Interface Builder. So when the CollectionView loads the first item can not be selected (causing an event to fire) as according to the array its already selected.

I have tried removing the selectedObjects in awakefromNib but its always empty as it seems that the Cocoa Binding is the last thing to happen somewhere after awakefromNib.

Maybe im going about this the wrong way but any ideas on this one would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you bound the array controller to the collection view itself, or to a column? Have you also bound the collection view's `selectionIndexes`?

Comment: @jtbandes - I have it working now but for anybody else looking over this post I was binding my array to the collection view and using cocoa bindings to bind properties of my CoreData model to labels etc on my prototype using representedObject.myModelProperty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable 'Avoid empty selection' option of your ArrayController in IB.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks a lot should have posted earlier and saved myself 2 hours trying to figure it out, undertaking manual binding etc.